# Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: certificate

I am not able to Sign in to the application as it is throwing the following exception:

```
com.ibm.wsspi.channel.framework.exception.ChannelException: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.xmlsoap.builders.WebServicesFaultProcessor.createFault(WebServicesFaultProcessor.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.xmlsoap.SOAPFault.getFault(SOAPFault.java:486)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.SOAPPart.getFault(SOAPPart.java:1090)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.SOAPPart.getFault(SOAPPart.java:747)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.Message.getFault(Message.java:883)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.Message.ifFaultThrowSelf(Message.java:863)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:279)
```

......

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy the newly added Cert data to a file and save it as “rsa.cert” or get the cert and name it as "rsa.cert"
2. Then open “ikeman.bat”
3. Open Key file(jks format) and then look for that certificate which you want to update (may be expired or near to expiry date or changed cert). Save the name of the cert which you want to change (for example these are the names of the certificates). Then click on that Cert and press the Delete button. Then Click on Add button and open the “rsa.cert” file which you save previously. Then give the name same as the name of the cert which you deleted.
4. Repeat the same process for the Trust File(jks format)
5. Restart the app server and run the application